# How to access kernel mode memory in user mode application in WinCe7

Tags: windows, embedded, kernel, windows-ce, device-driver

I have written a direct show filter and a video decoder driver for Win CE 7. The filter is loaded in the user mode and the decoder driver is loaded in the kernel mode. The filter need memory to receive the input buffers and it allocates this memory by calling a video decoder driver function. The decoder driver allocates memory and returns its virtual address from kernel space (>2GB) because it is loaded in the kernel mode. But this memory is not accessible for the filter because it is loaded in the user mode.

By considering the above scenario, how can I make the memory allocated by the video decoder driver accessible for the filter?

Comment: Well, can you not allocate the buffers in user space and pass them to the video decoder driver to fill up?

Comment: Basically the video decoder driver needs a buffer from filter that contains an encoded data. The video decoder driver takes this buffer, decodes the data and send it back to the filter.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will help considering you're on Win CE 7, but in Windows 7, I have a driver that maps a kernel mode address to a user mode address before returning the resulting user-mode address to my application.

```
void *userSpaceAddr;

// Allocate the MDL describing our kernel memory
pmdl = IoAllocateMdl((PVOID)&my_heap_var,
                     (ULONG)size_of_my_heap_var,
                     FALSE,
                     FALSE,
                     NULL);
if(!pmdl) {
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVVIDEO_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "Error on IoAllocateMdl. Returning from driver early.\n");
    return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
}

MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool(pmdl);

userSpaceAddr = (void *)MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache(pmdl, UserMode, MmWriteCombined, NULL, FALSE, LowPagePriority);
```

`userSpaceAddr`is mapped to a user space virtual address in the process context that called the driver. You can then return userSpaceAddr to your application.

This hinges on the MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache function. MSDN doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554629(v=vs.85).aspx